# Function repeat button?

Tags: javascript, function, button, repeat

So I want to create a simple button that repeats on-click a function. Example:

```
function example() {
document.write("Example")
}
```

For now, the function only runs:

```
Example
```

But I want to know how to make a simple button that can, for example, do this if clicked 3 times:

```
Example
Example
Example
Example
```

I also don't mind if at first there's nothing and the button simply runs the function for the first time, as long as the other results shows under the last one(s). How do I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say here, if you have bind an event to button click then it will execute every time that button is clicked.

Comment: Im kinda newbie sorry, that's exactly what I wanna do. So how do you bind an event to a button? (Also I think I already tried this but the button disappeared after it was clicked once...)

Comment: Oh.. ok. Now I see your problem. Your problem is `document.write` function call, when you do that; it wipes out all the content of page and write whatever you pass. So when you click on your button it will erase button and write Example string. So you should just do `console.log` instead if you are trying to check button click. Nothing wrong in your code; it's just the way of execution for document.write function.

Comment: So reason for button disappearing is `document.write` you should read about it in online docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doRepeat(funct, times){
    (function recurse(){
        funct();
        times--;
        if(times) recurse();
    })();
}
```

This function will repeat another function a given number of times. Use it like this...

```
// will call your example function 50 times.
doRepeat(example, 50);
```

---

edit.. as noted in the comments your button is being overwritten by `document.write()`. you should have explained that the reason you can't repeat the function is because the button is disappearing.

you should NEVER use document.write. in this case a better option is innerHTML. dont forget to add a line break too.

```
function example() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "Example<br>";
}
```

Comment: And what if I want to run it ''a certain amount of times'' instead of ''over a certain amount of time''? (Im not the downvoter)

Comment: that's not in the question, therefore is not a valid reason to donwvote.

Comment: OP's problem is not about repeating, that's basic HTML functionality: you bind event to a button and when you click it, everytime it will call that function (unless there is an error). Real problem is use of `document.write` which wipes out his button from screen, so button to click on next time.

Comment: @HarryJoy - thank your for pointing that out. i guess op didn't think that was important enough to add to the question. i've fixed the answer.

Comment: So basically, is it right to say that if i change all of my document.write("something") for document.body.innerHTML += "something" it will work?

Comment: OMG it works! Thanks a lot, I was looking for this for a while! Thank's guys for your support! Also I didn't post all of my code because the function I want to run is 1113 lines long, 96k length xD But anyway, i replaced all my document.write for document.body.innerHTML +=... and it worked. Thank's again <3

Comment: @zone53 - understood. happy to help. if this answer resolved your issue please click the check mark by the answer. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function example() {

   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "example</br>";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="example()">click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you.